# Codeigniter: Using PDO instead of mysql

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdo

Until Codeigniter implements the use of PDO, is there a way to use hack it into CI that's **stable and secure**? Currently, instead of using the db driver, I'm using a model instead which has all my PDO code like `prepare`, `fetch`, `execute`, etc. in it. What are the rest of you doing?

Comment: Using C.I's built in functions. CI is known for its speed and lightness, whats your reason on not using it?.

Comment: C.I. doesn't use PDO at all? What do they use for portability? Does the MySQL adapter really use `mysql_*()` functions?

Comment: I'm pretty sure CodeIgniter uses PDO under the hood.  EDIT: The MySQLi driver uses `mysqli_*`.  They have a [PDO Driver](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/drivers/pdo/pdo_driver.php) you can use.  EDIT2: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743943/codeigniter-pdo-integration).

Comment: For portability CI has an abstract DB API (`CI_Database`) with db-specific functionality implemented in drivers. The MySQL driver uses `mysql_*`. There are also `MySQLi` and `PDO` drivers. None of them use prepared statements because parameter-placeholder escaping is done by CI already.

Answer (score 9):

On **CodeIgniter 2.1.4+** using **MySQL** databases (Edit the file: /application/config/databases.php).

**To use PDO:**

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'mysql:host=localhost';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'pdo';
```

**To use MySQLi**

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
```

Comment: With CodeIgniter 3+, you now have to use `$db['default']['hostname'] = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database_name';` or you get en error stating "No database selected".

Answer (score 8):

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1; dbname=****yourdatabasename*****; charset=utf8;',
    'hostname' => '',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '******yourpassword*******',
    'database' => '',
    'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Answer (score 4):

Using PDO drivers instead of mysql require to change the hostname and the dbdriver like this :

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'mysql:host=localhost';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'pdo';
```

Answer (score 3):

CI, if used correctly, is both reliable and safe. Using PDO, while better if you are not using a framework, doesn't necessarily benefit you terribly over the CI_Database class.

If it really bothers you, you can swap out the `mysql_*()` functions for the equivalent `mysqli_*()` functions, but it really won't provide any discernable difference unless you are hyper-optimizing.

---

It should be noted that this can actually be done automatically by setting the dbtype appropriately (as Rocket notes below).

Comment: On a side note: I will say that the fact that the signatures are slightly different between CI's DB class and the PDO interface to be annoying, but not nearly as annoying as the difference between Mysqli and PDO.

Comment: Just set the dbtype to `mysqli` in CodeIgniter's config.  Then it'll use the mysqli functions instead of the mysql ones.

Comment: @Rocket That is a very good point. I was not aware of that option.

Comment: PDO is nice for stuff like Sentry.

Answer (score 0):

Just a follow up to anyone having this same issue (including my future self), please ensure that whichever dbdriver you are loading has the correct library loaded in php.ini

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli'; //MySQLi <-- mysqli.dll
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql'; //MySQL <-- mysql.dll
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'pdo'; //PDO <-- pdo.dll
```

Failure to load the correct dll will cause CodeIgniter to fail with a blank page.

Answer (score -1):

try [php-activerecord](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/) I believe this use's PDO driver, its a simple plug and play via sparks.